# Generate Web Report from SQL Server Database using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I need to access a table from SQl Server database and show the results in web format. There will also be a calendar control on the page. When user selects any past date and submits, the page should be refreshed with the corresponding data. User will not have access to change any data though.

The above functionality should also be scheduled in a way that everyday at a specific time, an email will be sent automatically to all the users having the web report link.

I have gone through some forums and many have suggested using SSRS.

Do you know if I can implement using only Asp.Net though VS ? If so, can you point me to the correct article. Please let em know if I have to incorporate any other missing pieces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish what you're after for the email piece by using a system such as Hangfire.  You can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HangFire/).